# How to check whether the port 80 is available using a batch file in windows xp

Tags: batch-file, windows-xp, port

I'm writing a batch file to automatically checks the port 80 availability and give an error message if it is using by another program. But I'm not sure how to check the port 80 availability in a batch file.

I found following command to check that with terminal.

```
 netstat -o -n -a | findstr 0.0:80
```

But I need to check it with a batch file like follows

```
if (!//port 80 is available) {
  // Give an error message
} else {
  // Continue with the rest
}
```

Can someone please help me on this.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could try in this way:

```
@echo off
netstat -o -n -a | findstr ZXCZXCZCZX 
if %ERRORLEVEL% equ 0 (@echo "port taken")
ELSE (@echo "port available")
```

When an item is not found FINDSTR will return an %ERRORLEVEL% > 0
(Tested on a command console in Windows 7 64bit)

Comment: It works fine with me. :) Can we output the program name which is using port 80

Comment: @Thilanka sorry, I have tried some variations but can't find a good solution. The problem is netstat and the flag -b which outputs the process name, but in a separate line and so findstr is unable to find it. Tried also tcpvcon from [Microsoft SysInternals](http://www.sysinternals.com) but the output doesn't contains the port number

Comment: The "netstat -o -n -a | findstr ZXCZXCZCZX"  command will anyhow print the output in the terminal. But the problem is it only print the id not the name. If we can allow it to print the name it will be enough.